# Format and spacing check using VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

Actually I want to check spacing and format of my Values Using VBA Macro. It is a dynamic string say 1 Count (Pack of 1) or 2 Count (Pack of 1), 20 g (Pack of 1) or 50 g (Pack of 2), 100 ml (Pack of 2) or 200 ml (Pack of 1). so the format remains the same but the integer alone changes in each cell. Also I wrote a code using instr function but it is not able to validate and give me the output. I want integer to be be defined as X and format should be the same.

I have mentioned the code below which I tried. I need some concept which can be helpful. I have attached the screenshot which needs to be validated. Thanks a lot.
[image]

```
Sub QualityCheck()
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim X(1 To 20000) As Integer



ActiveSheet.Select

Range("A1").Select
LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Columns.Select

ActiveCell.Value = "Quality Error"

Range("A1").Select

Set P = Range("A$1:AD$1")
For Each cell In P
    If cell.Value = "ASIN" Then cell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next

Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "DE" Then
        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12).Value Like " Stück ( er Pack)" Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26).Value = " Correct"
        
        End If
    End If
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    
Loop
    
End Sub
```

Also I have tried like declaring a varaible like X = 1 to 1000 and concat "X&" Stuck ("&X&"er Pack")" but still it didne work. It would be helpful if I get the syntax to crack the concept. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question looks like an excellent exercise for regular expressions in Excel VBA: I would advise you to search for the corresponding reference, add it (using VBA menu item "Tools", "References") and try to find the correct regular expression to check with.

Comment: To me it is not clear, which kind of checks you want to run. E.g.: would "24-teiliges Set" be wrong?

Comment: Yes for now I am trying only 1 stuck (1er Pack). The value will be in this format X Stuck (Xer Pack). The Value of "X" Can be any number. So I want to check whether the format and the spacing is correct without any mistake. if there is any error it will give incorrect which I didn't mention in the program for now.. I hope you understood my concept. Please provide me the logic if you have any. it would be most helpful @lke

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you need to modify this line:

```
        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12).Value Like "*Stück (*er Pack)" Then
```

This modification goes like this:

Any char - then followed by "Stück (" then ANY CHARS - followed by "er Pack)"

Should work, let me know if it did!

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Augustin, it worked but small correction "*Stück (" & "*er Pack)" the syntax should be like this and it worked flawless.. I already tried this syntax but it didn't worked. Now I just got a spark in my dumb head to clear it out.. Thanks for the suggestion